# How can I exclude nearly duplicated values in a sql table based off a rule?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider this table:

[image: this table]

I have data giving a person's ID and their citizenships.  Some people appear twice on the table because they have dual citizenship.
I would like help doing two things:

1) If someone has US citizenship and another citizenship, I would like to remove the line with the non-US citizenship

2) If someone has two non-US citizenships, I would like to remove one of them--no preference which.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "remove"? Remove it from the result of a query? Or delete those rows permanently from the table?

Comment: I mean don't include those rows on the query, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do:

```
select id, name, citizenship
from (
  select id, name, citizenship, 
         row_number() over (partition by id 
                              order by case 
                                         when citizenship = 'US' then 1 
                                         else 2 
                                       end) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

Another option is to use Postgres' `distinct on ()` operator

```
select distinct on (id) *
from the_table
order by id, by case 
                  when citizenship = 'US' then 1 
                  else 2 
                end
```

Comment: What about someone who does not have any US citizenship?  Wouldn't this exclude them?

Comment: @Dan: no, it would pick one at random